# Cannot read property 'field_273_raw' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I keep getting an undefined error whenever I try to use any of the data inside a JSON array, it's supposed to take the data from the webpage and use it to push it via a button to a separate webpage that merges it with a word document.

I declared the variable using

`const data_view_372 = Platform.models['view_372'].data.toJSON();`

and then I have a loop go through a shifts table and add it to my url variable.

```
for(a = 0; a < 3; a++){
  url += '&WorkDay'+ a +'='+ encodeURI(data_view_372[a].field_273_raw.identifier);
  url += '&HoursPerDay'+ a +'='+ encodeURI(data_view_372[a].field_289_raw);
  url += '&HoursPerWeek'+ a +'=' + encodeURI(data_view_372[a].field_290_raw);
  url += '&StaffPerShift'+ a +'='+ encodeURI(data_view_372[a].field_278_raw);
  url += '&PeriodTotalHours'+ a +'='+ encodeURI(data_view_372[a].field_289_raw);
  url += '&WeeklyTotalHours'+ a +'='+ encodeURI(data_view_372[a].field_290_raw);
  console.log(url)
}
```

I've tried researching what it could be but so far my only real progress was to try `.identifier` or `.field_273_raw[a].identifier` but neither have worked.

I'm probably missing something really obvious because I'm a beginner so please don't destroy me.

Comment: why did you add `.toJSON()` in your declaration? the result of that is a string, which, obvisouly, has no properties like the ones you use. Porbably just dropping that call will solve your problem.

Comment: What could lead you is `console.log(data_view_372);`.

Comment: The person who originally wrote the code on their site to link their platform to the one I'm using had it, I think it's because the thing I'm using this script on is a table but I'm not sure if I'm honest. Did try a console.log further down but it gave me the value of `["0"].field_273_raw.identifier` when I hovered over it in the console which is what I was using at the time.